# How to display Serial Numbers with mysql query result?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a script that displays information of these fields- batchname, class, batchinstructor from the table "batch". But I want to display dynamically generated serial number on the left side when I show the data. For example:

```
 Serial Number    BatchName     Class              Batch Instructor  
  1.               Solar      Class Five                John
  2.               Lunar      Class six                 Bon Jovi
```

I have tried a lot but its not working. Would you please kindly help me to solve this? Please note that these serial number are not from database.

Here's my Controller:

```
<?php
  class Batchlist extends CI_Controller{


                    function index(){

                    $this->load->library('pagination');


                    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'batchlist/index';
                    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('batch')->num_rows();
                    $config['per_page'] = 20;
                    $config['num_links'] = 20;
                    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination" align="center">';
                    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

                    $this->load->model('mod_batchlist');
                    $data['records']= $this->mod_batchlist->batch_list($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
                    $data['main_content']='view_batchlist';
                    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

                }
```

}
?>

Here's my Model:

```
function batch_list($perPage,$uri) { 
                        $this->db->select('*');
                        $this->db->from('batch');
                        $this->db->join('teacher', 'batch.batchinstructor = teacher.teacherid');
                        $this->db->order_by('batchid','DESC');
                        $getData = $this->db->get('', $perPage, $uri);
                        if($getData->num_rows() > 0)
                        return $getData->result_array();
                        else
                        return null;
                        }
```

Here's my View

```
<h1>Batch List  </h1>
            <?php if(count($records) > 0) { ?>
            <table id="table1" class="gtable sortable">
            <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Batch Name</th>
                        <th>Class</th>
                        <th>Batch Instructor</th>
                        <th>Edit/Delete</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($records as $row){ ?>


                    <tr>

                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>batch/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['batchname'];?></a></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['teachername'];?></td>
                        <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>updatebatch/get/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>" title="Edit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a>
                             <a href="#" title="Delete"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></a>
                             </td>
                    </tr>
            <?php  } ?>

            </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="tablefooter clearfix">

                        <div class="pagination">
                        <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?> 
                        </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I misunderstood, but...what about a simple counter?? (after you ordered your records in SQL).
You need to pass to the view the number of items per page (in this snippet: `$per_page`), then you retrieve the current page from the URI (`$this->uri->segment(n)`).

At page 1, counter starts from (20*0)+1, i.e. 1. At page 2, starts from (1*20)+1 ie 21, at page 3 from (2*20)+1 ie 41 and so on...

```
  <?php 
   $cur_page = $this->uri->segment(n) ? intval($this->uri->segment(n)) : 1;
   $i = (($cur_page-1) * $per_page) +1;
   foreach ($records as $row) : 
   ?>
  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $i;?>.</td>
      <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>batch/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>"><?php echo $row['batchname'];?></a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['class'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['teachername'];?></td>
      <td> <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>updatebatch/get/<?php echo $row['batchid']; ?>" title="Edit"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>support/images/icons/edit.png" alt="Edit" /></a><a href="#" title="Delete"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>support/images/icons/cross.png" alt="Delete" /></a>
      </td>
</tr>
<?php 
      ++$i;
      endforeach;
 ?>
```

You can place the counter wherever you want, I added a column for simplicity but if you want it somewhere else just place the counter there.

Answer (score 0):

You said the serial numbers are not from the database. Where are they from then? If you want the database to generate them you can create a column named id and set it as the primary key and have it auto increment.

Comment: Actually when you are displaying data you may want to show it in a listed order. For example you write some names Like this way- Bryan Adams, Bon Jovi, Steve Vai. But If you show this same thing in a listed order like 1. Bryan Adams 2. Bonjovi 3. Steve Vai . it looks better. This is what I want. I can guess the logic and that is after you made the query to fetch data, you count the number of rows in the result and then do some loop thing and display . Thanks for your help